# How to open a new activity with html on Android studio

Tags: java, android

I need to open a barcode scanner activity through a html page. When I try to tap on the barcode image it gives a warning. I have **MainActivity.java** and **BarcodeActivity.java** classes.

The warning when I click the barcode image:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(7027)] "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080", source: file:///android_asset/js/framework7.js (7027)
```

**MainActivity.java is**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    WebView webView =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl("file:////android_asset/index.html");
   
}
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().contains("activity.barcode://")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,BarcodeActivity.class));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".BarcodeActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="activity.barcode" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**index.html**

```
<li class="menuicon"><a href="activity.barcode://"><img src="images/icons/black/barcode.png" alt="" title="" /></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

possible that it never enters the if condition. getHost() may just return the hostname which is after "://", try to call getProtocol()

Comment: Can you elaborate about how I can do that?

Comment: replace Uri.parse(url).getHost() with Uri.parse(url).getProtocol()

Comment: like this: Uri.parse(url).getProtocol().contains("activity.barcode"

Comment: try getScheme()

Comment: didn't work either. So I debugged my code and it seems like shouldOverrideUrlLoading method is never entered. I think I have a problem on the html side but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I get this warning when I click the barcode image: I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(7027)] "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080", source: file:///android_asset/js/framework7.js (7027)

Comment: It is just an INFO, shouldn't cause your issue.